# Why must all list literals being concatenated be parenthesized in kdb to prevent type error, but the last one can be left unparenthesized?

Tags: kdb

What's this about?

```
q)(42+2*til 10),(til 10),til 3
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
q)(42+2*til 10),til 10
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

q)(42+2*til 10),til 10,til 3 / til 10 is not a list?
'type
  [0]  (42+2*til 10),til 10,til 3 / til 10 is not a list?
                     ^
q)type til 10
7h
q)type (til 10)
7h
```

Just wondering what the interpreter considers `til 10` to be there? Apparently only the last list can skip the parentheses. Why is that? What evaluation order occurs and what type does it produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter reads from right to left. Therefore the `10` is joined onto the resultant list from `til 3` before being passed to the `til` on the lefthand side. Putting in brackets will avoid this

```
q)10,til 3
10 0 1 2j
q)til 10 0 1 2j
'type
q)til[10],til 3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2j
```